# dplyr summarise_each standard error function

Tags: r, dplyr

I can summarise my data and calculate mean and sd values using:

```
summary <- aspen %>% group_by(year,Spp,CO2) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean,sd))
```

However, I cannot manage to calculate standard error as well. I tried this with no success:

```
summary <- aspen %>% group_by(year,Spp,CO2) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean,sd,se=sd/sqrt(n())))
```

Comment: You need to define a function to calculate the standard error, then to call it inside `funs`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `std.error` function from `plotrix` package or define your own function first and pass that function name as argument.

```
    library(plotrix)
    summary <- aspen %>% group_by(year,Spp,CO2) %>% 
summarise_each(funs(mean,sd,std.error)))
```

Answer (score 23):

You could do

```
library(dplyr)
aspen %>% 
    group_by(year,Spp,CO2) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(mean,sd,se=sd(.)/sqrt(n())))
```

For reproducibility,

```
data(mtcars)
grpMt <- mtcars %>%
          group_by(gear, carb)

grpMt %>%
     summarise_each(funs(mean, sd, se=sd(.)/sqrt(n())), hp:drat) %>% 
     slice(1:2)
#   gear carb hp_mean drat_mean     hp_sd   drat_sd     hp_se    drat_se
#1    3    1   104.0    3.1800  6.557439 0.4779121  3.785939 0.27592269
#2    3    2   162.5    3.0350 14.433757 0.1862794  7.216878 0.09313968
#3    4    1    72.5    4.0575 13.674794 0.1532699  6.837397 0.07663496
#4    4    2    79.5    4.1625 26.913441 0.5397144 13.456721 0.26985722
#5    5    2   102.0    4.1000 15.556349 0.4666905 11.000000 0.33000000
#6    5    4   264.0    4.2200        NA        NA        NA         NA
```

which is the same you get with `std.error` from `plotrix`

```
 library(plotrix)
 grpMt %>% 
    summarise_each(funs(mean, sd, se=std.error), hp:drat) %>% 
    slice(1:2)
 #  gear carb hp_mean drat_mean     hp_sd   drat_sd     hp_se    drat_se
 #1    3    1   104.0    3.1800  6.557439 0.4779121  3.785939 0.27592269
 #2    3    2   162.5    3.0350 14.433757 0.1862794  7.216878 0.09313968
 #3    4    1    72.5    4.0575 13.674794 0.1532699  6.837397 0.07663496
 #4    4    2    79.5    4.1625 26.913441 0.5397144 13.456721 0.26985722
 #5    5    2   102.0    4.1000 15.556349 0.4666905 11.000000 0.33000000
 #6    5    4   264.0    4.2200        NA        NA        NA         NA
```

Comment: Very nice! But there is a problem if missing values occur. I therefore recommend to use `summarise_each(funs(mean(., na.rm=T), n = sum(!is.na(.)), se = sd(., na.rm=T)/sqrt(sum(!is.na(.)))), hp:drat)`.
Please note that the function `n()` gets this wrong for calculating the correct standard error (and will result in alpha error inflation) so instead `sum(!is.na(.))` should be used.
If you want to check for your own data, just include the terms 
`n1=n(), n2 = sum(!is.na(.))`.

Comment: @MarioReutter  Yes, that is true, with `NA` values you need to use `na.rm = TRUE`.  I think the OP didn't specify any NA elements so, I didn't made any correction.  Also, I was modifying the OP's code

Comment: Of course. It wasn't meant as criticism but to complement your post. But please be aware that `na.rm = TRUE` is NOT sufficient because the `n()` function includes missing values resulting in standard errors being too low. I will add a small post to illustrate this.

Comment: @MarioReutter  I didn't take it as a criticism.  Yes, I do understand that it will fail in those conditions you described.  I would have done the same thing if the OP mentioned about the missing values

Answer (score 3):

Important add-on to @akrun:

If missing values (`NA`) can occur, you should use:

`summarise_each(funs(mean(., na.rm=T), n = sum(!is.na(.)), se = sd(., na.rm=T)/sqrt(sum(!is.na(.)))), hp:drat)`

Unfortunately, the `n()` function doesn't remove missing values so in addition to use `na.rm=T`, we need to replace `n()` by `sum(!is.na(.))`.

Illustration on how it can ge wrong with some of my own data:

`summarise_each(funs(
    mean(., na.rm=T), n1=n(), n2=sum(!is.na(.)), 
        se1=sd(., na.rm=T)/sqrt(n()), se2=sd(., na.rm=T)/sqrt(sum(!is.na(.)))), rating)`

[image: dplyr n() includes NAs]

`n2` and `se2` are the correct values.